# Fortran FORMAT statement

Tags: format, fortran

I am trying to read in the following in line:

> 110134458.602 7  20957861.900

My format line is currently as follows:

```
READ(7,110,END=999) L1,C1,D1
write(*,*) L1,C1,D1
110 FORMAT(F14.3,1x,F1.0,2x,F14.3)
```

However the output I am receiving is:

> 110134458.60200000        7.0000000000000000        20957861.899999999

Why do I have so many decimal places and why is the final value not match?
Thank you!

Comment: [Rounding errors?](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: @arxanas: no, not rounding errors, typical behaviour of floating-point numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks that you are reading the values correctly.  With list-directed IO for the output the compiler will typically use the maximum number of digits for the numeric type.  Not all decimal values will have exact finite precision binary equivalents -- that is probably what you are seeing for the 3rd number.   If you use a format statement for the output, specifying fewer digits, the value will get rounded and appear correct.

Comment: I modified the write statement to match the read format which fixed the decimal problem, however now it is not reading the number 7 correctly and is giving me a * instead.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: I changed it to an I1 instead of F1.0 and the problem was solved.  Thank you